# django - how to restrict number of pages an unauthenticated user can view

Tags: django

I am building a website using django (1.10). I want to restrict the number of pages that an unauthorised person (i.e. a user that is not logged in), can view.

The desired behaviour is that after visiting N different pages, the user is directed to a specific page.

In other web platforms I have used (Symfony), there is a way of doing this by writing custom "filters" and session variables - I think django provides similar affordances via it's concept of **midleware** - however, not sure if this is the way to go, to implement this requirement.

How best may I implement this requirement (**unauthorised user directed to a custom page after viewing N different pages**), using the django framework?

Comment: Is it only for one session? Or for a period of time?

Comment: I think that a custom decorator is the best solution for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
if has_attr(request, 'page_count'):
    request.page_count += 1
else:
    request.page_count = 1
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/) how to implement `middleware`:

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
# One-time configuration and initialization.

def middleware(request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    response = get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response

return middleware
```

Or:

```
class SimpleMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Edit:
If you are using a `class` implement it so:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.page_count >= <count>:
        return redirect(<your redirect here>)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll get started using this as a starting point. Just to clarify, where is the page count (and redirect if appropriate) logic being inserted in the middleware code?

Comment: The page count is updated in your function or class. You need to add the `middleware` in your settings. And you could do the redirect in your view or or directly while processing the request.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a middleware is the right place. Middleware runs on every request and it has access to the current request and session, and the user object if the middleware is run after SessionMiddleware and AuthenticationMiddleware (depends on the order in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting).

You can save the number of pages seen on the setting, and if it's over the limit then return a HttpResponseRedirect from the middleware.

Of course the user can always throw away his session cookie or start an incognito browser tab, that can't be helped.

See the middleware documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/ .

Comment: Tracking USER_AGENT also will help i think.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich could you please post a snippet that illustrates how to do this - or at least a link to such an example?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: added a link to the docs, this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich no, it's not, but it is common practice to add snippets. It can happen that the link will no longer be available and people that are looking for help will find your answer a wee bit useless.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich no need for the snarky remark - this is about coders helping coders, no one is forcing you to respond to my question.